# how to dynamically add the delete and update buttons in every row of my asp.net web table which is generated at run time

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am trying to learn asp.net at my own so i have already learned how to insert data in sql server and how to fetch it from the database and display it in table dynamically but the thing i am trying to do is that I want 2 buttons of delete and update in every row which is linked to the same row only and if i click delete button of row 1 it will delete that row entirely from the web and sql server also.
here is the code i am using to fetch data from sql-server and displaying it in the table on button click...

```
protected void DisplayData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cd = new SqlCommand("select * from signup",con);
            SqlDataReader rd = cd.ExecuteReader();
            if(rd.HasRows)
            {
                while(rd.Read())
                {
                    TableRow row = new TableRow();
                    TableCell cell1 = new TableCell(); 
                    cell1.Text = rd[0].ToString();
                    TableCell cell2 = new TableCell(); 
                    cell2.Text = rd[1].ToString();
                    TableCell cell3 = new TableCell(); 
                    cell3.Text = rd[2].ToString();
                    TableCell cell4 = new TableCell(); 
                    cell4.Text = rd[3].ToString();
                    TableCell cell5 = new TableCell(); cell5.Text = rd[4].ToString();
                    TableCell cell6 = new TableCell(); cell6.Text = rd[5].ToString();
                    row.Cells.Add(cell1); 
                    row.Cells.Add(cell2); 
                    row.Cells.Add(cell3); 
                    row.Cells.Add(cell4); 
                    row.Cells.Add(cell5); 
                    row.Cells.Add(cell6);
                    Table1.Rows.Add(row);
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: An ASP GridView control would probably help you here, rather than creating the table manually. It has hooks for edit/delete buttons built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You and add buttons with:

```
TableCell btnCell= new TableCell();
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Id = "Id";
btn.Text = "Something";
btn.Click += new EventHandler(BtnHandler_Click);
btnCell.Controls.Add(btn);

row.Cells.Add(btnCell);
```

The event

```
protected void BtnHandler_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    // Do something
}
```

Note: Have a look at [GridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview?view=netframework-4.8), which seems like a better alternative for what you want to achieve.

Comment: i have done this thing but it is not hitting the eventHandler when i click the button

Comment: Dynamic controls need to be added on the page on every post back to fire events properly.

Comment: can you please explain it?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
//Update Button
TableCell cell7 = new TableCell();
Button btn1 = new Button();
btn.Id="btnUpdate";
btn.Text = "Update";
btn.Click += new EventHandler(btnUpdate_Click);
cell7.Controls.Add(btn1);

//Delete Button
TableCell cell8 = new TableCell();
Button btn2 = new Button();
btn.Id="btnDelete";
btn.Text = "Delete";
btn.Click += new EventHandler(btnDelete_Click);
cell8.Controls.Add(btn2);

// add above two cell objects to row object
 row.Cells.Add(cell7);
 row.Cells.Add(cell8); 

//Update button event handler
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    // update the record
}

//Delete button event handler
protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    // Delete the record
}
```

Comment: nice answer sir buttons are now showing. but the problem now is that  this code is not hitting the event handler on click of buttons. I used debbugers also but they are not hitting why is that?

Comment: do one thing 
add

`<asp:PlaceHolder ID="placeHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>` in your .aspx page and in code behind 

`placeHolder.Controls.Add(Table1);`  add your Table Object to the page

Comment: i Have added the asp table before in aspx with a header row and coloums. and adding more rows dynamically from here.